# PHP - How to access android apps report from Google Play Develop Console?

Tags: php, google-play-developer-api

I want to access monthly installs reports from Google Play Store in PHP.
I have not find any Google Play Store API for same.
Can any one help me on this ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is possible in two ways**

1. Download reports using a gsutil (command line tool)
2. Download reports using a client library & service account

refer this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export) for more information